# Full responsive background image

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I try to understand how can i do the full background image responsive.
at first i am using jQuery Anystretch.

The code.

> functions.php

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery.anystretch', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.anystretch.js', array( 'jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.anystretch');
```

> main.css

```
.imgheader { background: url("images/image.png")  height:450px; width:100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; position: relative}
```

> index.php

```
<figure class="container imgheader"> </figure>
```

> header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
(function() 
{
$('.imgheader').anystretch("images/image.png");
})
});
</script>
```

Also, i try with :

```
   $('figure.imgheader').anystretch("images/image.png");
```

From the documentation :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.imgheader').anystretch("images/image.png", {speed: 150});
});
</script>
```

3rd edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('figure.imgheader').anystretch("images/image.png", {speed: 150});
});
</script>
```

4th update:
The problem is the same with jquery-backstretch. I am loading the plugin for the full background image and the image which is inside the container, and didn't work. With the help of Firebugs i see that the js is loading in the page.  I see again a couple of hours and i am back.

But the problem is the same, the script do not load. What i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the image is actually at the path you're giving any stretch?  Can we see a live example?

Comment: Sorry, but i can do that. I am working locally.

Comment: Assuming you have confirmed that the image is indeed there, try deleting everything but the essential css rules for .imgheader, and make sure .imgheader is a div, not a span or something.  Try it with just width and height.

Comment: I try. Nothing happens.the problem remains

Comment: Ok, I can't debug every line for you if I can't see the live code, but I went ahead and set up a working anystretch demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ8BQ/  Try and work backwards from there.

Comment: You have right. You can't debug if you can see the live code. I clean the code and i see again and again. From Php to css and js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's happening here, but if you don't get this working I can advice the use of [jquery backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch). I have used it myself a couple of times in projects and it always gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and i am be back.

Answer (score 4):

Couple things, there's no need to enqueue jquery, it's bundled with WordPress core and all files will have it available if you set up your javascript properly.  In your functions.php, make sure you wrap it in an add action call like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts_function');
function my_scripts_function() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.anystretch.js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.anystretch.js'); // you don't need the third parameter here
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.anystretch.js');
}
```

Ideally, you would just enqueue another javascript file of your own rather than put in header.php, but it will work *sometimes* doing it this way.  Your issue was the additional function() wrap I believe, don't see any need for it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.imgheader').anystretch("images/image.png");
});
</script>
```

If this isn't working, confirm that jquery and anystretch are loading on the page you're trying to run them on.

Comment: The solution that you propose me can not solve my problem. Also i check that the js loading on the page.

Comment: Ok, what is it "not solving"?  You said the issue was the script not loading.  If it's loading, there's an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am little confused because i do many things. With the Firebugs i see that js is loading.

Comment: Ok, what specifically isn't working?  In the anystretch documentation a speed is always passed, have you tried that?

Comment: Started commenting up there.

Answer (score 1):

i have try in different ways with multiple jquery plugins like `jquery.ez-bg-resize`, `jquery.backstretch`, `jquery.anystretch`. Even now I can not think why js do that. For these plugins js is loading but the result is the same. My problem didn't resolve. 
Then i thought to do that with the help of css to media queries, for these with this way the problem approximately solved.

```
imgheader { background: url("images/images.png")  50% 50% no-repeat scroll !important;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
```